# mvc4 DB update exception when adding record

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having difficulty fixing this error, I have a model named **profile** and I sometimes add records to that model and it works fine. I however added another model at the end of the model **profile** and now it gives me an update exception

```
  public class profile 

{
   [Key]
  public  int ID { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
    public following follows { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I added **public following follows** at the end because it makes it easier for me to use the dapper ORM with models embedded like that. The issue I'm having is that when adding a new record to the **profile** model it gives me an update exception because of the **public following follows** is there any way I can fix this?

```
                     model.name="John Doe";
                    db.profiles.Add(model.profile);
                    db.SaveChanges();
```

See this code above always executed but not it does not because it states that **public following follows** can not be null, how can I make it nullable?

One other thing the **following model** is as such

```
    public class following
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? me { get; set; }
    public int? ProfileID { get; set; }

}
```

and my DB exception error says **Follows_ID** can not be null.

Here is the complete code

```
             [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(homepage model)
        {

                     model.name="John Doe";
                    db.profiles.Add(model.profile);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("complete");

    }
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Model Code or Database first?

Comment: @Kye I think he is using code first assuming by looking at model `profile`

Comment: That is a good question, I'm very new to this. I essentially create the model first and then manually create the database table because it is not generated for me.

Comment: Would you please post your complete code for the section above db.SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that exception because you are instantiating `Following` but not setting the id. But you will still face the issue even after adding id to the `Following` model. I would adivce you to make `model.follows = null;` This should solve the error.